# Search button and textfield not on same baseline

Tags: html, css, forms

Why are the blue search button and white textfield not starting from the same height? How can I fix this?
The URL is ...

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You have a different padding on your button and your textfield.

I have a good looking search bar when applying this style to the submit button:

```
.blueButton {
  padding: 1px 0;
}
```

(edit: according to Chrome's developers tools, there is a "2px 6px 3px" padding applied by default on buttons)

Comment: Thanks, me too :), but instead of 1px I used 1em!

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the `font-size: 1em;` made them aligned for me.  So, you can resize the font or resize the height.